# System Cannot boot when trying to install 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 for two days now.
Thats something pretty strange because normally thats done in about half an hour.

It doesn't boot whatever I try. I got several different types of not-booting until now.
All without significant error messages.

Now that I'm running out of ideas I thought maybe one of you is able to find my mistake.
The boot info is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/1265205/

If you need any other information I'd be happy to provide it.

Comment: Are you installing from CD or USB?  Have you tried the Alternate install?

Comment: Did you correctly create the partitions? Like "/" & "SWAP"?

Comment: I can't see any obvious errors in the install.  Grub is installed on the MBR of /dev/sda, is trying to boot off /dev/sda4, and fstab is pointing the correct devices for / and swap.  Does it boot to the grub menu?

Comment: I managed to get the grup prompt, unfortunately not the grub menu. For this I had to include a copy of my linux drives bootsector into the windows bootmenu. I also found out that this is hardwarespecific with lenove ideapad s205. Tried all the fixes I could find so far but I I don't get past the grub prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Try typing F12 in the first booting, But first you must copy the installation file in USB or CD. It should be appear ubuntu complete installation proccess